# ApexCharts dynamically set chart height to number of shown rows (horizontal bar chart)

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, gantt-chart, apexcharts

I am trying to dynamically adjust the height of an **ApexChart**
(**horizontal bar chart** as in https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/timeline-charts/advanced/)
dynamically as the number of shown lines changes when clicking the legend links.

I am currently counting the number of shown rows through 
document.querySelector(".apexcharts-yaxis-texts-g").childElementCount;

No matter if I add an event listener from outside the charts object or
when I use the events in the chart options, im **ending up in a vicious circle** as
the number of rows is always counted **BEFORE** the redraw of the chart occurs with more or less rows.

This will leave me with the "previous" number of rows to adjust the chart´s height.

Has any of you changed an ApexCharts' height on runtime ?
Not talking about the responsive options or the general %heights here
but strictly about changing the chart´s height depending on the number of shows rows.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I experience this issue too, one way I dynamically set the height of the barchart is to set it's height to the length of the data * the height each bar should have i.e data.length * 50